# Is swallowing dead sperm Zina or still a graveful sin?

Tags: halal-haram, zina

Today, I was wondering if swallowing dead sperm a Zina or a graveful sin. What is the punishment for it if it is both or just one of them?

Comment: How'd you encounter this problem and considered it worth asking? Just asking, no offense meant.

Comment: @sorrel-vesper I used to masturbate and used to touch my computer, smartphone, inside my nose or door knobs right after (to enter my bathroom) and anytime I assumed that the sperm was dried and dead. And my other family members touch these items too. So, this morning, I became worried about it and I couldn't find much information on the Internet, that is why I am asking it here.

Comment: @azam, I was talking about sperm which has died when it is dried, when it is no longer a fluid.

Answer (score 1):

As salaamu alaikum,

Swallowing sperm would be impermissible due to its being filth. However, there is no punishment for swallowing it. Pray to Allah for forgiveness and avoid repeating it.

In reference to touching areas where sperm has been and consequently dried then there is no transfer of filth and no harm to those who may have touched those areas. The issue or concern would be with the area of prayer and the clothes or accessories one prays with.

If, for instance, there was sperm on the rug but a prayer mat was placed over it. There would be no problem with praying in that area. However, if there was, for instance, sperm that was on a cell phone and you prayed with the cell phone in your pocket it would be best to make up the prayer if you remembered within the prayer time. Otherwise, if the prayer time exited the prayer would be sound, Insha'a Allah.

and Allah knows best.

Comment: Note that I am not married. The reasons of my issue is in the comments above (in the original post). But, what about if someone else touches it? Will I get punished for it?